# How can I obtain a new id for created entity in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have weird situation, I'm getting some random id after inserting a row into the database, through EF Core 5.0, but I don't get the corret `Id`.

```
// Insert into Clients table
Client client = new Client();
client.Projects = projects;
client.IdentityId = registeredUser.Data;

_context.Clients.Add(client);

Result<int> res = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

// it returns for example 2 but id with 2 already 
// exists in database (for a different row)
var a = res.Data;

Result<ClientResponse> response = new Result<ClientResponse>();

response.Data = new ClientResponse
{
    Email = command.Email,
    Name = command.Name,
    Projects = projectsResponses,
    Id = a
};

response.Message = "Client added.";
response.Succeeded = true;

return response;
```

Comment: I tried also with client.Id (I hoped that will be updated with a new value, but client.Id is 0), maybe it's because I dont have annotaion in my Client class `[Key] for Id property?`

Comment: Can we see what the `Client` type looks like? Also the EF configuration for it?

Answer (score 3):

The result from the `await _context.SaveChangesAsync()` method returns the number of records affected only. To get the actual ID assigned to the new record, it should be on the property that is designated as the primary key on the `Client` table, which I presume is either `Id` or `IdentityId` in your code above.

Edit: Quick note that you should not set the primary key value yourself for `inserts`. Let EF Core set it for you. EF will fill it in *after* the `SaveChangesAsync` method completes.

Answer (score 2):

fix your code

```
var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
If(result==0) .... return error 

// result is a number  of affected rows
    //result should be 1 in this case since only 1 record should be added

var response = new Result<ClientResponse>();
response.Data = new ClientResponse
{
    Email = command.Email,
    Name = command.Name,
    Projects = projectsResponses,
    Id = client.Id  //after saving Id is automatically assigned
};
.....
```